# Eval ViewState value on a server control tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

Is there a way to Eval the ViewState value on a server control tag?

```
<asp:TextBox    Text='<%#Eval(Viewstate["key"])%>' runat='server' />
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Icarus it means using data binding expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a watch for that ViewState value, or set a breakpoint and use the Immediate Window.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you, i don't want to get the value by debugging it (if thats what you meant). I want to use it in the code.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I understand now. Is this TextBox in a databound control?

Comment: In reality i want to set the visible property of a control inside a gridview to a value within the viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

**edit** Changed answer to better suit your requirement to set visibility on a control.

Sticking a databind() in the code behind after setting the Viewstate value will work. e.g.

aspx.cs : -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ViewState["Test"] = "hello";
    DataBind();
}
```

aspx : -

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHello" runat="server" visible='<%#  ViewState["Test"].ToString()    == "hello"  %>' Text="Show Hello"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

will "show hello" but if you change the viewstate value to something else it won't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# ViewState["key"] %>'/>
```

The <%# %> annotation means whatever is within provides access to codebehind. In this case, it will access ViewState and retrieve the item saved under "key". As a result, the @Text of the label will be whatever the value of ViewState["key"] is.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Of course, I should have done that. I edited the entry for better visibility.